# Is it possible to host a windows console in a headless unit testing runner like resharper?

Tags: c#, .net-core, console-application, integration-testing, pinvoke

I have a software library which targets console applications. I would like to run a slim set of integration tests that use the windows Console in a headless runner that would ideally be run on our build server and in the resharper test runner.

To make this work, I need the actual `System.Console` calls to be executed in the test (so they can't be conditionally commented out.)

When the tests call something that the requires the stdout handle, e.g. `Console.SetCursorPosition`, an exception is generated: `System.IO.IOException: 'The handle is invalid'`

I assumed I could just do a pinvoke and call `FreeConsole` and `AllocConsole` and this would allow me to call the relevant methods. Unfortunately this doesn't appear to be the case.

At the moment I can successfully Free, Alloc, and redirect console output back to STDOUT but this doesn't change the exception behaviour. Any ideas?

I'm redirecting STDOUT back to CONOUT using the following:-

```
var stdoutFile = ExternalMethods.CreateFile("CONOUT$", FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read, IntPtr.Zero, FileMode.Open, FileAttributes.Normal, IntPtr.Zero);
var handle = new Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafeFileHandle(stdoutFile, true);
if (handle.IsInvalid)
{
    throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
}

if (!ExternalMethods.SetStdHandle(-11, handle))
{
    throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this working in the end. It was necessary to create a sub-process with CREATE_NO_WINDOW flags, wait until the process had started a new console session, and then attach to the sub-process.